# How to handle a DB update with server actions with different forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-action

I have several forms in UI dashboard such as "edit title" and "edit description". Each form basically has one input element.
I want to handle database updates and with server actions in next js 14. On the front end I use `useFormState`.

I achieve want I want, but does a more elegant code exist like this on. These ongoing repetition doesn't feel nice.

```js
const VideoUpdateSchemas = {
  title: z.object({
    title: z.string().min(1, { message: "Feld darf nicht leer sein." }),
  }),
  description: z.object({
    description: z.string().min(1, { message: "Feld darf nicht leer sein." }),
  }),
};

export type UpdateState = {
  message?: string;
  errorsTitle?: {
    title?: string[];
  };
  errorsDescription?: {
    description?: string[];
  };
  success: boolean;
  status?: number;
};
export async function updateVideo(prevState: UpdateState, formData: FormData) {
  const rawFormData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
  const videoId = rawFormData.id as string;
  delete rawFormData.id;

  let validatedFields;
  if (typeof rawFormData.title === "string") {
    validatedFields = VideoUpdateSchemas.title.safeParse({
      title: formData.get("title"),
    });

    if (!validatedFields?.success) {
      return {
        errorsTitle: validatedFields?.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
        success: false,
      };
    }
  }
  if (typeof rawFormData.description === "string") {
    validatedFields = VideoUpdateSchemas.description.safeParse({
      description: formData.get("description"),
    });
    if (!validatedFields?.success) {
      return {
        errorsDescription: validatedFields?.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
        success: false,
      };
    }
  }

  try {
    const video = await prisma.video.update({
      where: {
        userId,
        id: videoId,
      },
      data: {
        ...rawFormData,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      success: false,
    };
  }
  revalidatePath(`/dashboard/videos/${videoId}`);
  return {
    success: true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Half of your code is related to validation. Each form has its own unique validation logic. You could use `zod` to write validation logic. For example:

```
import { z } from "zod";

const updateViceoSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(3),
  videoId:z.string().min(5)
  // add validation logic for each field
});
```

In your action:

```
const result = updateViceoSchema.safeParse({
    title: formData.get("title"),
    videoId: formData.get("videoId"),
  });

if (!result.success) {
    return {
      errors: result.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
    };
  }
```